# Retain HTML tags on JSON to XML conversion

Tags: c#, json, xml, json.net

I have a JSON object which I convert to XML using the following code:

```
private string ConvertFileToXml(string file)
{
    string fileContent = File.ReadAllText(file);
    XmlDocument doc = JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(fileContent, "root");

    // Retain html tags.
    doc.InnerXml = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(doc.InnerXml);

    return XDocument.Parse(doc.InnerXml).ToString();
}
```

where `string json` is the following object:

```
{
  "id": "2639",
  "type": "www.stack.com",
  "bodyXML": "\n<body><p>Democrats also want to “reinvigorate and modernise” US <ft-content type=\"http://www.stack.com/ontology/content/Article\" url=\"http://api.stack.com/content/d2c32614-61c6-11e7-91a7-502f7ee26895\">antitrust</ft-content> laws for a broad attack on corporations.</p>\n<p>Mr Schumer said the Democrats’ new look should appeal to groups that backed Mrs Clinton, such as the young and minority groups, and members of the white working-class who deserted Democrats for Mr Trump. </p>\n</body>",
  "title": "Democrats seek to reclaim populist mantle from Donald Trump",
  "standfirst": "New economic plan is pitched as an assault on growing corporate power",
  "byline": "David J Lynch in Washington",
  "firstPublishedDate": "2017-07-24T17:51:25Z",
  "publishedDate": "2017-07-24T17:50:25Z",
  "requestUrl": "http://api.stack.com/content/e8bec6dc-708d-11e7-aca6-c6bd07df1a3c",
  "brands": [
    "http://api.ft.com/things/dbb0bdae-1f0c-11e4-b0cb-b2227cce2b54"
  ],
  "standout": {
    "editorsChoice": false,
    "exclusive": false,
    "scoop": false
  },
  "canBeSyndicated": "yes",
  "webUrl": "http://www.stack.com/cms/s/e8bec6dc-708d-11e7-aca6-c6bd07df1a3c.html"
}
```

and the output of the method generates this:

```
<root>
  <id>2639</id>
  <type>www.stack.com</type>
  <bodyXML>
&lt;p&gt;Democrats also want to “reinvigorate and modernise” US &lt;ft-content type="http://www.stack.com/ontology/content/Article" url="http://api.stack.com/content/d2c32614-61c6-11e7-91a7-502f7ee26895"&gt;antitrust&lt;/ft-content&gt; laws for a broad attack on corporations.&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;Mr Schumer said the Democrats’ new look should appeal to groups that backed Mrs Clinton, such as the young and minority groups, and members of the white working-class who deserted Democrats for Mr Trump. &lt;/p&gt;
&lt;/body&gt;</bodyXML>
  <title>Democrats seek to reclaim populist mantle from Donald Trump</title>
  <standfirst>New economic plan is pitched as an assault on growing corporate power</standfirst>
  <byline>David J Lynch in Washington</byline>
  <firstPublishedDate>2017-07-24T17:51:25Z</firstPublishedDate>
  <publishedDate>2017-07-24T17:50:25Z</publishedDate>
  <requestUrl>http://api.stack.com/content/e8bec6dc-708d-11e7-aca6-c6bd07df1a3c</requestUrl>
  <brands>http://api.ft.com/things/dbb0bdae-1f0c-11e4-b0cb-b2227cce2b54</brands>
  <standout>
    <editorsChoice>false</editorsChoice>
    <exclusive>false</exclusive>
    <scoop>false</scoop>
  </standout>
  <canBeSyndicated>yes</canBeSyndicated>
  <webUrl>http://www.stack.com/cms/s/e8bec6dc-708d-11e7-aca6-c6bd07df1a3c.html</webUrl>
</root>
```

Within the original `"bodyXML"` of the JSON, there is HTML text with HTML tags but they get crushed into HTML entities after the conversion. What I want to do is retain these HTML tags after conversion.

How do I do this?

Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Are you *sure* that's what you want to do? Any errors in the HTML excerpt you include would cause your entire XML file not to parse (in fact, in your example,  there is a closing `</body>` tag without a matching start tag). How about just reforming the HTML tags at the point of decoding?

Comment: Yes I am sure that I want to retain the HTML tags.

Comment: @Phylogenesis how do I reform the HTML tags at the point of decoding?

Comment: Whatever process is reading the XML file just has to decode the XML entities.

Comment: @Phylogenesis the reason for that invalid body tag was due to my own error when cutting down the original code to post here. I have modified the code to include this again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think its possible to have the 'Encoded' HTML tags in the inner text of an xml Node

But its possible to do an HTML Decode on the inner text of that Xml Node after you parse the XmlDocument.

This will get you the text with all the HTML tags intact.

Eg.,

```
private static string ConvertFileToXml()
    {
        string fileContent = File.ReadAllText("text.json");
        XmlDocument doc = JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(fileContent, "root");
        return System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(doc.SelectSingleNode("root").SelectSingleNode("bodyXML").InnerText);
    }
```

Namespace required : System.Web

Comment: This worked, I adapted the new code into my original post

Comment: No worries mate !